# Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plan

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join to two datasets

Ds1

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|  countryName|countryPopulation|countrySize|
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|        China|       1210004992|    9596960|
|        India|        952107712|    3287590|
| UnitedStates|        266476272|    9372610|
|    Indonesia|        206611600|    1919440|
|       Brazil|        162661216|    8511965|
|       Russia|        148178480|   17075200|
|     Pakistan|        129275664|     803940|
|        Japan|        125449704|     377835|
|   Bangladesh|        123062800|     144000|
|      Nigeria|        103912488|     923770|
|       Mexico|         95772464|    1972550|
|      Germany|         83536112|     356910|
|  Philippines|         74480848|     300000|
|      Vietnam|         73976976|     329560|
|         Iran|         66094264|    1648000|
|        Egypt|         63575108|    1001450|
|       Turkey|         62484480|     780580|
|     Thailand|         58851356|     514000|
|UnitedKingdom|         58489976|     244820|
|       France|         58317448|     547030|
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Ds2:

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| countryName|countryPopulation|countrySize|
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
|       China|       1210004992|    9596960|
|       India|        952107712|    3287590|
|UnitedStates|        266476272|    9372610|
|   Indonesia|        206611600|    1919440|
|      Brazil|        162661216|    8511965|
|      Russia|        148178480|   17075200|
|    Pakistan|        129275664|     803940|
|       Japan|        125449704|     377835|
|  Bangladesh|        123062800|     144000|
|     Nigeria|        103912488|     923770|
|     Germany|         83536112|     356910|
|     Vietnam|         73976976|     329560|
|        Iran|         66094264|    1648000|
|    Thailand|         58851356|     514000|
|      France|         58317448|     547030|
|       Italy|         57460272|     301230|
|    Ethiopia|         57171664|    1127127|
|     Ukraine|         50864008|     603700|
|       Zaire|         46498540|    2345410|
|       Burma|         45975624|     678500|
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

When I perform below operation I ge the output

```
  Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds2.filter(ds2.col("countryPopulation").cast("int").$greater(100000))
        .join(ds1, ds1.col("countrySize")
                .equalTo(ds2.col("countrySize")));
  ds3.show();
```

But when I do below operation, I'm getting error

```
  Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds2.filter(ds2.col("countryPopulation").cast("int").$greater(100000))
        .join(ds1, ds1.col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType)
                .equalTo(ds2.col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType)), "inner");
  ds3.show();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [country#6.name AS countryName#2, country#6.population AS countryPopulation#3, country#6.area AS countrySize#4]
+- Filter (isnotnull(country#6) && (Contains(country#6.name, a) && ((cast(country#6.population as int) > 100000) && (cast(country#6.area as int) = cast(country#6.area as int)))))
   +- Generate explode(countries#0.country), [0], false, t, [country#6]
      +- Relation[countries#0] json
```

May I know Please how should cast and join at the same time..? And why am getting this error..?

What's a meaning of this "Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans" in error ?

Comment: can you use cast("int") instead of .cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).

Comment: @Nikk, Tried..Its giving same error.

Comment: It could be conflicting on the same column name. Can you try after aliasing the columns: `ds1.col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).alias("size1").equalTo(ds2.col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).alias("size2")`:

Comment: @Gsquare, Nope..Its giving same error.

Comment: can you try Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds2.filter(ds2.col("countryPopulation").cast("int").$greater(100000))
        .join(ds1, ds1.col("countrySize").cast("int")
                .equalTo(ds2.col("countrySize").cast("int")));

Comment: @dassum, Its samee error..btw the one you had shared already tried..!

Comment: The code that you're showing us doesn't match the plan in the error message. Specifically, where is the condition for `country#6.area` coming from?

Comment: What is the data type for ‘countrySize’? It seems function call in join condition is causing cartesian. Can you try to apply the cast function while selecting and don’t add cast while joining

Comment: @Salim, How ...?

Comment: The comments space is too small to describe. I am adding an answer. I hope nobody down votes it

Answer (score 0):

I have seen cartesian join happens when the where condition contains a function call with parameters from both data frames. Something like `df1.join(df2, aFunction(df1.column, df2.column)`. Here I don't see that exactly but I suspect something like that is going on.

Try below to get the function applied on select condition rather than where.

```
    Dataset<Row> ds1_1 = ds1.select(col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).as("countrySize")) // add all columns here

    Dataset<Row> ds2_1 = ds2.select(col("countrySize").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).as("countrySize"),ds2.col("countryPopulation").cast("int").as("countryPopulation")) // add all columns here

    Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds2.filter(ds2_1.col("countryPopulation").$greater(100000))
        .join(ds1_1, ds1_1.col("countrySize")
                .equalTo(ds2_1.col("countrySize")), "inner");
    ds3.show();
```

Comment: In your last Dataset ds3, you are filtering data from ds2 but joining ds1_1 and ds2_1 ...why is it so ....?

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code, the only thing I added is to apply cast function in select rather than in join condition. Change the code as you wish, just avoid function call in join clause. if it works upvote it please.